# Notifications in laravel - data display

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, notifications

I have a question. I created a notification system, I did so that the notifications are added to the table: 'notifications'. At the beginning, I tested on users, it displayed data through:

```
    @foreach(Auth::user()->notifications as $notification)
            <h5> {{ $notification->data['user_id']}}</h5>
        <p>{{ $notification->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</p>
    @endforeach
```

The data was displayed without any problem. I made a few changes and things started to add from a different table. It's cool, but I can't display the data from this new table.

```
public function toDatabase($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'player_id' => $this->player->id,
        'text' => $this->player->text,
    ];
}
```

If I set it in the view, an error pops up.

```
{{$notification->data['player_id']}}
```

Error: Undefined index: player_id

Comment: Hi there, what is the output of `$notification->data`?

Comment: I have error: "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given".